# Should I unlock bootloader before changing from Cyanogen to Lineage OS

Tags: cyanogenmod, lineageos

My phone is YU Yureka (AO5510) Which comes with **Cyanogen pre-installed but not rooted**. I bought it 2 years back and I am still at CM 12.1 which is based on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop and I am not getting any OTA updates.

I would like to change from CM 12.1 to Lineage OS 14

The question is,
 *because of some internal issues, Cyanogen OS is dead and the code then forked and maintained as Lineage OS. Also the codename is same (Tomato for my device).*

So, should I unlock the boot loader to install the Lineage 14 or without unlocking am I able to install it?

Comment: What's the reason *not* to unlock? I mean, there are countless examples where people get stuck and can't recover just because they have a locked bootloader, turned off OEM Unlocking in OS, and can't boot.

Comment: The reason is Lineage is similar to cyanogen. IThe same code is forked and maintained by a new community. Will it be treated as official rom(since cyan is dead)?

Comment: Cyanogen OS is different from CyanogenMod - not "the same code". COS is more geared towards the mass, therefore contains a bunch of closed-source services, plus no root built-in for security sake. As far as I know, YU loads their phones with Cyanogen OS. Can you verify?

Comment: @AndyYan please check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzEbo.png

Comment: The kernel version, it is CyanogenMod

Comment: Did you not notice the "Cyanogen OS version" on top? You have COS. The kernel version there only means that a machine from CyanogenMod built the kernel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59397/discussion-between-andy-yan-and-sagar-v).